# SOLVED - truffle develop command doesn't return anything

Tags: truffle

I updated my node and nvm version. Then I ran **truffle develop** command on my project folder, this command doesn't return anything.. why?

it just stays... local blockchain dosen't start.

Versions:

```
Truffle v5.1.25 (core: 5.1.25)
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v14.2.0
Web3.js v1.2.1
```

I removed the truffle on my machine and than I installed again but I get same result.

Also **truffle console** command result is here:

```
> Something went wrong while attempting to connect to the network. Check your network configuration.

Could not connect to your Ethereum client with the following parameters:
    - host       > 127.0.0.1
    - port       > 7545
    - network_id > 5777
Please check that your Ethereum client:
    - is running
    - is accepting RPC connections (i.e., "--rpc" option is used in geth)
    - is accessible over the network
    - is properly configured in your Truffle configuration file (truffle-config.js)

Truffle v5.1.25 (core: 5.1.25)
Node v14.2.0
```

SOLVED:

**I downgrade the truffle from 5.1.x to 5.0.x** and truffle develop is ran.

Comment: Are you on windows? I'll suggest downgrading node. The last version of node that worked for me without problems was node 10. As an alternative you can try WSL.

Comment: No, on macOS. Actually it was working properly. I updated the node then truffle develop mode did not up.

Comment: Anyway I'll suggest to try downgrading node to version 12, node 14 is just too new perhaps some dependency isn't working correctly.

Comment: the error continues... also I edited and add **truffle console** command result. what is the problem?

Comment: There are some remaining issues with node 12 https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/2070. Using node 10 on windows and node 12 on linux work for basic development.

Comment: I looked this but I couldn't a solution. :(

Comment: I have the same version and I'm having today the same issue. Also I will try the downgrade to 5.0.x.

Comment: `truffle develop` v5.1.43 is working on my mac now once I switch to Node <14

Comment: Downgrade node version to version 12 using nvm or node.exe

Answer (score 3):

Node 12 works with truffle version 5.0.x and 5.1.x

I had to downgrade node that I installed through 'brew install node' which installed node version 14.12.0.

steps to downgrade node using brew...

1. brew install node@12
2. brew unlink node
3. brew link --force --overwrite node@12

back in your truffle project folder

$ truffle version

Truffle v5.1.47 (core: 5.1.47)

Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)

**Node v12.18.4**

Web3.js v1.2.1

truffle develop should now work...

Answer (score 0):

had a similar issue. all I had to do was uncomment the development key under networks in the truffle.config.js and the contracts migrated to dev blockchain just fine.

[image: screenshot - truffle.config.js]

Answer (score 0):

I just closed vscode and restarted the laptop. And the truffle develop command started working.